# Migrating to the New Places SDK Client cannot find symbol variable PLACE_DETECTION_API

Tags: android, migration

I can't migrate my Android script has error cannot resolve symbol "Geo_data_api"
this is my full code.

```
package in.techware.lataxi.activity;


     mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();
```

What the wrong with this?

Comment: Unfortunately what you have been looking for is deprecated. Refer https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceDetectionApi

Answer (score 0):

> The way you doing is deprecated You can see the latest migration from the link [Migrating to the New Places SDK Client](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)

Answer (score 0):

> The Places SDK for Android introduces an all-new static library with updated functionality. The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (i.e. com.google.android.gms:play-services-places) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019.

You have to migrate to the new [Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration).

Answer (score 0):

Now you don't need to use GoogleApiClient class.
code is deprecated and you have to migrate your old code to new.

I'm posting the new way to do this.

```
etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                recycleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getPlaceAutoCompleteUrl(s.toString());
            } else {
                recycleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgCancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    public void getPlaceAutoCompleteUrl(String input) {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = 
        RetrofitClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("json?input=");
        try {
           urlString.append(URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        urlString.append("&location=");
        urlString.append(mylocation.getLatitude() + "," + 
        mylocation.getLongitude()); // append lat long of current location to show nearby results.
        urlString.append("&radius=500");
        urlString.append("&sensor=true");
        urlString.append("&language=en");
        urlString.append("&key=" + getString(R.string.mapKey));
        Log.d("Destination", "apiInter URL " + urlString.toString());
        Call<GooglePlaceModal> call = apiInterface.getGooglePlaces(urlString.toString());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GooglePlaceModal>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GooglePlaceModal> call, Response<GooglePlaceModal> response) {
                Log.d("Destination", "apiInter response " + response.body().getPredictions().size());
                if (response.body()!=null && response.body().getPredictions()!=null &&response.body().getPredictions().size() > 0) {
                    recycleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list = response.body().getPredictions();
                    GooglePlaceAdapter(this, list, mWidth);
                    recycleView.setAdapter(placeAdapter);
                    placeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GooglePlaceModal> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
       });

    }
```